# My font awesome does not appear and I cannot figure out why

Tags: font-awesome

I have this font-awesome icon that I wanted to used for some reason it is not showing.I cannot to figure out why

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" 
 integrity="sha384- 
 UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">  



<div id="boxIcon2">
<i class="fas fa-car"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this a normal HTML site or are you using any framework ?

Comment: it is normal HTML. My main misunderstanding is that it work prior on my other section of the HTML but doesn't appear for this specific section

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you are really running exactly that same code?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out it was my background it stop it from showing they were blend in together